# How to delete a node in a linked list in c

Tags: c, linked-list

what i need to do is to implement a function in c for deleting a node in a linked list, using a for and while loop with strcmp. The program compiles fine but the loop never stop, any suggestion on how to make it better?

The structure is this:

```
struct Test
{
 char name[16];
 int id;
};

typedef struct Node
{
 struct Test  structure;
 struct Node * next;
}TNode;

typedef TNode * Nodo;
```

And the function i wrote is this:

```
void Delete(Nodo * pp)
 {
  Nodo i;
  char temp[16], name[16];

  printf("Insert the name to delete:");
      scanf(" %s", name);

for(i = *pp; i->next != NULL ; i = i->next)
  {
    if(strcmp(i->structure.name, name) == 0)
      {
        while(i->next != NULL)
        {
          strcpy(temp,i->structure.name);
          strcpy(i->structure.name, i->next->structure.name);
          strcpy(i->next->structure.name, temp);
          i = i->next;
         }
      }
   }
 }
```

UPDATE: The working function is this, thanks to Some programmer dude for the explanation:

```
void Delete(Nodo * pp)
{
  Nodo i, prev;
  char name[16];

  printf("Insert the name to delete:");
     scanf(" %s", name);

//case for the first node

  if(strcmp((*pp)->structure.name, name) == 0)
  {
    Nodo old = *pp;
    *pp = (*pp)->next;
    free(old);
    return;
  }

//loop to delete node inside list

  for(prev = *pp, i = prev->next; i != NULL ; prev = i, i = i->next)
  {
    if(strcmp(i->structure.name, name) == 0)
      {
        prev->next = i->next;
        free(i);

        break;
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: A best practive is not to hide pointers in typedefs. You got for example me caught in the confusion that creates...

Comment: Note that your function can not handle an empty list, or a list of only one node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sub>[Note: This doesn't actually answer the question, but it tells how to unlink nodes in a single-linked list, which IMO is the bigger problem the OP have.]</sub>

Lets say you have the following list

```
+---+    +---+    +---+    +---+
| A | -> | B | -> | c | -> | D |
+---+    +---+    +---+    +---+
```

If you want to remove node `B` then you don't copy the contents of the remaining list. Because that would give you the follow list:

```
+---+    +---+    +---+    +---+
| A | -> | C | -> | D | -> | D |
+---+    +---+    +---+    +---+
```

And that's not correct.

Instead you make the `A` node's `next` pointer point to `C` instead, so now the list becomes

```
+---+    +---+     +---+    +---+
| A | -\ | B | /-> | c | -> | D |
+---+  | +---+ |   +---+    +---+
       \-------/
```

Then you just `free` the node `B`, and you end up with

```
+---+    +---+    +---+
| A | -> | c | -> | D |
+---+    +---+    +---+
```

---

The trick to unlinking the node is to keep track of the *previous* node. It could be implemented something like this:

```
// Special case: Removing the first node in the list
if (strcmp((*pp)->structure.name, name) == 0)
{
    TNode *old = *pp;  // Save a pointer to the node that should be removed

    *pp = (*pp)->next;  // Actually unlink the node from the list

    free(old);  // Free the memory of the old node

    return;
}

TNode *prev;  // To keep track of previous node
TNode *curr;  // The "current" node

for (prev = *pp, curr = prev->next; curr != NULL; prev = curr, curr = curr->next)
{
    if (strcmp(curr->structure.name, name) == 0)
    {
        // Found the node to remove
        prev->next = curr->next;  // Unlink the current node from the list

        free(curr);  // Free the node

        break;  // No need to iterate anymore
    }
}
```

The "special case" of the first node being removed could also be solved inside the loop, by initializing `prev` to `NULL`, and start `curr` with `*pp` instead. Then you need to check if `prev` is `NULL` or not inside the `if` in the loop.

The code might look like more, and it might be more lines (even after removing some or all of the empty lines), but I think most people would say it's easier to follow and see what's going on.

Of course, you also need to add a check for an empty list and that `pp` itself is not null (like `pp != NULL && *pp != NULL`).

Comment: What if, after copying, i free the last node? Instead of A-C-D-D it will become A-C-D, also if i want to remove, let' say C, first the list will become A-B-D-D, i free the last node an it becomes A-B-D. Pls tell me if this reasoning works.

Comment: @St3veR0nix Yes it works, but it's lot more work than just changing a single pointer. And would probably confuse many programmers looking at your code, since changing pointers when dealing with lists is the common way to do it.

Comment: Btw, i'm still having trouble on how to figure it out, can you reply with some code?